# Perform calculation (label)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, label

I am new in coding and i need some of guidance and help from you guys here. I am creating a car rental system. When user click one of car in the list, it will be stored in session(the price). Then they need to select the rental days(in drop down list) and chauffeur service (select yes or no). Lets say 1 day the rental fee is **$30.** Then day of rental is **3** days and chauffeur service is **$15**. So the calculation will be **$30** x **3** = **$90** + **$15** = **$105**. The problem now, how to write in code all the calculation. All the bold numbers I write in label. Sorry for my bad English. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

convert the label text to integer/float based on your requirement

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(label.Text.ToString().Trim());
```

I think this is you want based on your question.I could not comment now.. :-(

Comment: Its ok Nag. Thnks for your answer. I'll try soon. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code

```
        public float calculate(float rental, int days, bool servcieSelected, int chauffeurService)
    {
        float totalAmount = (rental * days) + (servcieSelected ? chauffeurService : 0);
        return totalAmount;
    }
```

and call this function like this:

```
float total = calculate(30.0f, 3, true, 15);
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function like this, and call it, then store result in Session["total"].

Have some static variables:

```
const float rental_fee = 30.0;
const float chauffeur_service = 15.0;

public static float getTotalCost(float days, bool include_chauffeur)
{
      float total = (days * rental_fee) + (include_chauffeur ? chauffeur_service : 0);
      return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dane. I'll try ya solution soon. Cheers :)